# elasticsearch-full is returing error while I am trying to install using homebrew

Tags: elasticsearch, homebrew

I am trying to install elasticsearch-full using homebrew. I am using the below command.

```
brew tap elastic/tap     
brew install elastic/tap/elasticsearch-full
```

and it is returning bellow error.

```
Warning: Calling bottle :unneeded is deprecated! There is no replacement.
Please report this issue to the elastic/tap tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core):
  /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/elastic/homebrew-tap/Formula/elasticsearch-full.rb:9

Error: No such file or directory - /usr/local/var/homebrew/linked/elasticsearch-full
```

Please find the java version,
[image]

can anyone help me to fix this. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

I just ran into this issue today. I found a solution in an issue comment in the elastic repo. I'll link the comment below, but here are the steps I took to fix this:

```
brew remove elasticsearch-full
brew untap elastic/tap
brew update -v
brew tap elastic/tap
brew update -v
brew install elasticsearch-full
```

You can do this with any other affected packages by adding the package names after `elasticsearch-full`

Here's the link to the original issue comment for credit:
https://github.com/elastic/homebrew-tap/issues/110#issuecomment-964778575

Comment: i kept getting errors, so the flow instead would be `untap` > `tap` > `install`

Answer (score 5):

Check out the comment here. This works!
https://github.com/elastic/homebrew-tap/issues/146#issuecomment-1616542113

```
in /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/elastic/homebrew-tap/Formula/elasticsearch-full.rb:68.
```

it is working for me. Or

```
  service do
    run opt_bin/"elasticsearch"
    require_root false
    working_dir var
    log_path var/"elasticsearch.log"
    error_log_path var/"elasticsearch.log"
    environment_variables ES_JAVA_HOME: "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.11.jdk/Contents/Home"
  end
```

Comment: This solution is working without any issues!

Answer (score 5):

After `brew tap elastic/tap`, do this in the console:

```
cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/elastic/homebrew-tap
git fetch origin pull/144/head:patch-1
git checkout patch-1
```